# Why is count not accurate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

Here's the idea: the user can add items and they populate in a listbox control. If the user has no items, they should not be able to submit the form. However, I add an artificial item when there are no items using:

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    lstItems.Items.Insert(0, "No items have been added.");
}
else
{
    lstItems.DataSource = ds;
    lstItems.DataTextField = "ItemInfo";
    lstItems.DataValueField = "Item_ID";
    lstItems.DataBind();
}
```

Later, I want to ensure there are items before submitting, but the DataSet (`ds`) is not available in that function/context. To resolve this, I declared a global variable (public int) within the class that could be referenced:

```
public int numItems = 0;
```

Then set it like so:

```
numItems = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```

That way it wouldn't be thrown off by the one artificial record I inserted in `lstItems`. However, this isn't working. The value remains 0, even thought the above conditional statement evaluates correctly indicating that the row count is *not* 0. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this? I considered using:

```
if (lstItems.Items.Count < 1)
{
    // allow submission
}
```

But the problem with this is that it hits off my artificial item:

```
lstItems.Items.Insert(0, "No items have been added.");
```

So what is the best way to check if there are any user-created items in the list?

Comment: what page event does this occur in?

Comment: @ps2goat it occurs within a method to populate the items, which is called inside page_load after verifying the page is not a postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numItems is initialized to **0** on postbacks you wont be able to get the value in button click...

use some thing like this

```
ViewState["count"] =  ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```

and check the count on button click

```
if(Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]) > 0)
{
// your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user adds an item, remove your default item from the list. Then instead of basing validation on the count of items using a global, you can then base it on whether or not your artificial item exists in the list.

Comment: I already remove it from the list when they add items, but I can't figure out how to see if it is the only one there.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is the only one there, it only matters that it is there at all. If it is there, then they have not added any items, and fails validation, if it is not there, then they have added an item, and passes validation.

Comment: I get that, but I don't know how to check for that. A code sample would be helpful.

Comment: ListBox.Items.FindByValue(String)